# Plot won't show in Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to python and I began to teach myself how to use pandas on jupyter using the exercise from this link:

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jvns/pandas-cookbook/blob/v0.1/cookbook/Chapter%201%20-%20Reading%20from%20a%20CSV.ipynb

I have the problem that the plot at 1.3 won't appear when I do it in Jupyter, I only get the following output:

```
matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x8ad24a8>"
```

However it does appear when I run the same code in Spyder. Does anyone know why this is?  This is my code:

```
 import pandas as pd
import os
fixed_df = pd.read_csv('bikes.csv', sep=';', encoding='latin1', parse_dates=['Date'], dayfirst=True, index_col='Date')
fixed_df['Berri1'].plot()
```

Comment: add `get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')` after importing packages

Comment: @Ashish, `%matplotlib inline` is a cleaner way to achieve that.

Comment: @Ashish & cel thanks but neither of those worked, they just resulted in a much longer error message.

Comment: You can try the solutions which are mentioned [here](http://goo.gl/CxchpX). Let's hope that one of them works for you.

Comment: Can you show the error message?

Comment: @IanS I didn't realize that the error message didn't show. The post has been edited with the error message. Thanks.

Comment: Actually that's not an error message, it's just the plot object being shown as a Python object instead of being displayed. It really looks like you should use `%matplotlib inline`. Does it show the same output then?

Comment: ok It seems that %matplotlib inline has solved it when I opened a new file and tried it all again. Thanks!

Comment: Note that you will have to restart the notebook and have the `%matplotlib inline` call **before any plot commands**. You can't change matplotlib backend after initialization.

Comment: @HannesOvrén Thanks, I didn't know that!

Comment: @HannesOvrén thanks, yeah not restarting it is why `%matplotlib inline´ didn't work at first :)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

add the code below before your plots:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Comment: Thanks! I added this line & my Jupyter notebook started to display all the plots.

Comment: this worked for me on Jupyter notebook. I had to restart the kernel to get it to work.